# Extracting multiple csv file information from a path in pc with python and manipulate it at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-manipulation

I have multiple (say more than 20/30) CSV files named as **'ABCD.csv','EFGH.csv','IJKL.csv','MNOP.csv' etc** in my folder path **D:\sevenday** . I want to add a column named **name** in each CSV file and add their respective names inside the CSV file itself. Let us say, **ABCD** CSV file will have a column named **name** and it will have **ABCD** as a name in that column. How could I extract that string information from the file's name in python? Is there a way?
There are ways if files are few. But I don't know how to extract many files like that at once as writing each time one by one is tedious.

Comment: Sure, just write to each of the CSV files and then read the data back.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. But the problem is there are many CSV files in that path. so, declaring one by one will be tedious. So, I wanted to know how could I declare them to extract them at once and make a function so that I won't have to do it again and again. I've edited the question. thank you.

Comment: @buran - Hmmm, I think this is incorrect dupe, only part dupe, can you find better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glob` for get all files from your folder to list, add new columns and write back:

```
import glob, os

files = glob.glob('D:/sevenday/*.csv')

for fp in files:
    name = os.path.basename(fp)
    df = pd.read_csv(fp)
    df['name'] = name
    df.to_csv(fp, index=False)
```

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    csv_file = "ABCD.csv"

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

    df["name"] = csv_file.replace(".csv","")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. But the problem is there are many csv files in that path. so, declaring one by one will be tedious. So, I wanted to know how could I declare them (the 1st line in the code) to extract them at once and make a function like your code so that I wont have to do it again and again. I've edited the question. thank you.

Comment: you can use for loop

Comment: How can I use for loop here in this line when `csv_file = "ABCD.csv"` I have to write every name manually. Because if there are more than 30 files don't  I have to write each CSV file name one by one? I was confused here.

Comment: @JewelRanaPalit please check my new code comment. if you like it please give +1

Comment: I did. BUt to be counted It says I need at least 15 repu. I am new here yet.Thank you a lot

Comment: I did not get you in last comment. did you get the result or not?

Comment: This shows an error like `df.to_csv(csv_file. index=False)
             ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: It should be comma before index=False

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

folder_path = 'D:\\sevenday'

file_type = '\*.csv'

files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)

for csv_file in files:
    
     df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

     df["name"] = csv_file.split("\\")[-1].replace(".csv","")

     df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
```